# Javascript: why a variable undefined in inner function, even though the variable declared and assigned in the global

Tags: javascript

```js
let a = 1;
function outer() {
  console.log(a);

  function inner() {
    console.log(a);
    var a = 3;
  }
  inner();

  console.log(a);
}

outer();
```

why 'a' is undefined in the inner function above? shouldn't it be able to find a = 1 in the first line through scope chain?

inner function is inside outer function, and outer function is inside the global scope.

Comment: Variable declarations are hoisted. The inner function is equivalent to `var a; console.log(a); a = 3;`. `var` declarations are initialized with `undefined`. If you used `let` you would get an actual error (thus making you aware that you made a mistake).

Answer (score 3):

It is because of Javascript [hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)

Your `inner()` function is equal to -

```
function inner() {
    var a;
    console.log(a);
    a = 3;
}
```

which would obviously output `undefined` in the console.

Comment: but what about the outer function ? it prints out correctly

Comment: outer function output global `a`.

Comment: based on your answer, shouldn't 'a' in the outer function prints out undefined?

Comment: @facVV: The outer function doesn't contain a variable declaration for `a`.

Comment: let a = 1;
function outer() {
    var a;
    console.log(a) --> undefined
    ...


}

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the scope, here is a way how you can do this..

```js
let a = 1;
function outer() {
  console.log(a);
let newA = a
  function inner() {
    console.log(newA);
  
  }
  inner();

  console.log(a);
}

outer();
```